# I need to convert a python programme that merge the content of two files into one

Tags: python

```
def read_file(filename):
    
    with open("files/file1.txt", "r") as f1:
        content1 = f1.read()

    with open("files/file2.txt", "r") as f2:
        content2 = f2.read()
    
    return content1, content2
    


def merge_file_to_one(content1,content2):
    content1 += "\n"
    content1 += content2
    with open("files/file3.txt", "w") as f3:
        f3.write(content1)


merge_file_to_one(content1, content2)
```

i have tried to adopt your code into mine using my file names but I still cant make sense out of it. In the first function, am I supposed to just read one file. What happens to the second file.
/when I finally called the function, I get an error that content 1 and content 2 wasn't defined.

Comment: Did you read the part of the Python tutorial already where they show how to define functions?

Comment: So you need to define content1 and content2, or give them default variables inside the function e.g. `def merge_file_to_one(content1=" ", content2="/")`

Answer (score 0):

Taking your program and making it into functions you get:

```
#helper function to read file
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f1:
        content1 = f1.read()
    return content1

# Python program to merge the content of two files into a third
def convert_files_to_one(filename_one_read, filename_two_read, write_to_file):
    content1 = f"{read_file(filename_one_read)}\n{read_file(filename_two_read)}"

    with open(write_to_file, "w") as f3:
        f3.write(content1)

convert_files_to_one("files/file1.txt", "files/file2.txt", "files/file3.txt")
```

using the 'with' context manager is usually a better form than closing the files manually

Also when things are repeated it's best to put it into a function, so that you can reuse that logic easily elsewhere.